# Javascript how to push a new element from an initial array to each array inside an array of arrays at the same index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, types

I want to add new property to an array from another array using indexes of both.

For example, lets say I have the following array:

```
initArray = [
  { name: 'John', family: 'Doe'},
  { name: 'Joanna', family: 'Doe'}
];
```

And the array that I want to take from it and push it into `initArray`:

```
genderArray = [
  { gender: 'Male' },
  { gender: 'Female' }
];
```

What I need is a final array that be like:

```
initArray = [
  { name: 'John', family: 'Doe', gender: 'Male'},
  { name: 'Joanna', family: 'Doe', gender: 'Female'}
];
```

I tried the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
  Object.keys(this.genderArray).forEach((idx) => {
    console.log(this.initArray)
    this.initArray[idx].push(this.genderArray)
  });

  console.log(this.initArray)
}
```

But it returned an error of:

> Error: _this.initArray[idx].push is not a function

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-into-another-woth-same-indexes-9qxndx).

Comment: You're pushing to an element, rather than to an array

Comment: Looks like you're trying to push to an object. The object is part of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not push to `initArray`: you do not *add elements* to `initArray`, but instead *add a property* to each of its elements.

One possible way to do that:

```
Object.assign(this.initArray[idx], this.genderArray[idx]);
```

... or, if for some reason you want to create a completely new array of new 'enriched' objects, instead of modifying objects directly:

```
this.initArray[idx] = {...this.initArray[idx], ...this.genderArray[idx]};
```

Second, do not use Object.keys() to go through an array: use either `forEach()` if you do all the transformations inside the function or `map`, if you return a new element and want to have a new array in the end.

So your function might look like that:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.genderArray.forEach((element, index) => {
    Object.assign(this.initArray[index], element);
  });

  console.log(this.initArray)
}
```

... or ...

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.initArray = this.initArray.map((element, index) => {
     { ...element, ...this.genderArray[index] }
  });

  console.log(this.initArray)
}
```

Personally, I always find code 'x = x.map(transformer())` highly suspicious (if one reassign anyway, why not use forEach?), but it's up to implementation style choices.

---

If there's more than property in the elements of an array to be 'mixed', but you only want to take one, you can either go direct:

```
Object.assign(this.initArray[idx], { gender: this.genderArray[idx].gender });
```

... use destructuring in assignment:

```
const { gender } = this.genderArray[idx]; 
Object.assign(this.initArray[idx], { gender });
```

... or just bite the bullet and do assignment straight as we did in the good old syntax-sugar-free days:

```
this.initArray[idx].gender = this.genderArray[idx].gender;
```

In this particular case the last one looks like the best approach actually. Its disadvantage is having to repeat the property name, but that might also come handy if you want the props to be named differently in source and target arrays.

Comment: Cool, but what if the genderArray has 2 properties, and I only need one to push to `initArray` ?

Comment: In this case you should replace genderArray[index] reference with either quite direct `{ gender: genderArray[index].gender `, or do it in a bit different way - but perhaps clearer -I'll describe in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually trying to "merge" objects in two arrays.

There are many ways to implement this, but I think the clearest one is with the `Array.map` and `Object.assign` functions:

```js
const initArray = [
  { name: 'John', family: 'Doe'},
  { name: 'Joanna', family: 'Doe'}
];
const genderArray = [
  { gender: 'Male' },
  { gender: 'Female' }
];

const ans = initArray.map((person, index) => {
  const genderedPerson = Object.assign({}, person, genderArray[index]);
  return genderedPerson;
});
console.log(ans);
```

- `Array.map` iterates an array and modifies its elements.
- `Object.assign` extends an object, adding it additional properties from another object(s).

Comment: Strictly speaking, `Array.map` should not modify elements of original array; it's used to create a new collection based on some transformation of the original. So one could use something like... `return { ... person, genderArray[index] }` instead.

Comment: @raina77ow You're right, and I modified my answer so the generation of `genderedPerson` doesn't modify `initArray` as well. I LOVE the spread operator, however I think explicit syntax is clearer for beginners

Comment: Spread op is nice, but it's often misused, adding a small penalty for no real reason each time it's used instead of Object.assign. Here's more about it - https://medium.com/better-programming/the-reduce-spread-anti-pattern-fc0c1c0b23f6

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to use `array.push()` on an object, which doesn't work.

Instead, you could use a `for` loop to go through the array, and simply add a 'gender' category to that index by assigning a value to it, namely the gender at that index in the other array:

```js
initArray = [
  { name: 'John', family: 'Doe'},
  { name: 'Joanna', family: 'Doe'}
];

genderArray = [
  { gender: 'Male' },
  { gender: 'Female' }
];

for (var i = 0; i < initArray.length; i++) {
  initArray[i].gender = genderArray[i].gender;
}

console.log(initArray);
```

Alternatively, you could use `array.forEach()`:

```js
initArray = [
  { name: 'John', family: 'Doe'},
  { name: 'Joanna', family: 'Doe'}
];

genderArray = [
  { gender: 'Male' },
  { gender: 'Female' }
];

initArray.forEach(addGender);

function addGender(_, i) {
  initArray[i].gender = genderArray[i].gender;
}

console.log(initArray);
```

Comment: Use this if you work with environment that doesn't support ES5. Otherwise it'll a bit harder to read - and `i` variable will stay with you through the whole function's scope.

Comment: If I want change it from `for (var...)` into `for (const of ...)`, how can I access the index in this case? @raina77ow

Comment: @alim1990 I'm not really sure it's a good idea to use `for...of` here - it's created to iterate over elements when indexes are not relevant, and that's not the case here. Why don't you just use .forEach()? This function's purpose match the case exactly: do something for each element of the original array, but do not return the result.

Comment: @raina77ow I've added a solution that uses `array.forEach()` to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can merge two arrays by [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method using [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) spread operator:

```
const result = initArray.reduce((a, c, i) => {
   a.push({...c, ...genderArray[i]})
   return a;
},[])
```

or one line version:

```
const result = initArray.reduce((a, c, i) => (a.push({...c, ...genderArray[i]}), a),[])
```

An example:

```js
let initArray = [
  { name: 'John', family: 'Doe'},
  { name: 'Joanna', family: 'Doe'}
];

let genderArray = [
  { gender: 'Male' },
  { gender: 'Female' }
];

const result = initArray.reduce((a, c, i) => {
   a.push({...c, ...genderArray[i]})
   return a;
},[])

console.log(result)
```